# material-ui - change height, paddingTop of Dialog

Tags: angular-material, material-ui, mddialog

I am trying to have a dialog's height change to make to display all content inside it.

Also, I want to reduce the padding-top of modal to give me more space ....

How could I do it?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "to make to display all content inside it" ? Your content is not completely displayed in your dialog ? Anyway if you want to change it's height you can use this CSS rule `md-dialog { height: / your custom height /; }` (but be carefull mdDialog has a max-height, override it if you need)

Comment: Yup, when the content gets too large the dialog height doesn't increase and the content is hidden. I would like the dialog to expand to wrap the content inside it. I would also prefer not to set the dialog height, that is I would like the height of the dialog to be relative.

Comment: @DrkStr Is it completely hidden or if there is a scrollbar ?

Comment: Cause the regular behavior of a dialog is to enlarge the dialog window and to put a scrollbar when it's necessary, like in [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/oQ7sSrO1SMWk6S1KkSZO?p=preview). So i don't really get what you want ? You want to increase the maximum size of a dialog window ?

Comment: I am hiding the scroll bar, would that stop the dialog from expanding ?

Comment: @DrkStr I don't think so. But I think the only way you have to make the dialog as big as possible (without being bigger than the window) is to use **max-width** and **max-height** on **md-dialog** tag. Look at [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/oQ7sSrO1SMWk6S1KkSZO?p=preview) and tell me if it's what you want to do ?

Comment: Yup, that is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.How do I give you the bounty ?

Comment: @DrkStr I answer the question to do so ! :)

Answer (score 2):

So if you want to set a bigger maximum size to your **mdDialog**, you can do it by changing its **max-width** and/or **max-height** like this :

```
md-dialog {
  max-width : 95% !important;  // 95% is a example
  max-height : 95% !important; // You can set any size you want (in %, px, em, etc)
}
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/oQ7sSrO1SMWk6S1KkSZO?p=preview) is a working example.